# How to properly implement a Model/Controller/View web design?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am using Java-ee and eclipse to build my website.
I'm confused.

Java Beans, Servlets, jsp, html5, css3, java classes, java script, php....Model, View, Controller....

All I want to do is design a good looking website and a database for a school project. To do so I'm using java-ee with eclipse, a tomcat server and a mySQL database.

My problem is, there seems to be 10 million different ways to do so and overlapping languages on top of that!

Currently, my design consists of jsp pages and java classes, and css3 files for making things look nice. I have a jsp page, and if I need something done, I create a java class and do it in there. Also, every page links to different ones, its like a giant web.

I know this is a bad design, so my question is, how to I design a good model view controller setup and witch languages should I need? Why would I ever use javascript or php, when I can use plain old java and html4/5?

---

edit

Here is an example of how I use my jsp pages.

[image]

Comment: Using a framework is generally a good idea when learning, because the point of them is enforcing this structure in your code. I'd look into [Play!](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaTodoList). It's idiosyncratic and flouts a bunch of Java web app conventions. However, this is in the interest of making development more comfortable. Another upside is that it doesn't presuppose any knowledge of said conventions, and the documentation should explain even the basic stuff.

Comment: thanks, I will look in to it. I really want to do it with eclipse since I got it to work which was a pain...but maybe I can follow plays structure.

Comment: Eclipse should be able to work with the source structure just fine, you just won't have to care what the hell an appserver is before you can do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there by separating the logic (Java) from the view (JSP), so long as you're keeping all logic and data manipulation OUT of the JSPs. Next up is separating the logic (controller) from the data (model).

If you're not using any kind of framework, this would be done by encapsulating all of your business logic into Servlets, each acting as a controller; and all of your data into a set of Model classes (generally fairly basic Beans, and a set of DAO classes to load/store data between the DB and your Java objects). So, the DAO class (usually one for each entity type) connects to the database, requests a record, transfers the columns into the properties of a new instance of the appropriate model class, and returns that instance for use by the Controller/View.

Your  Controller servlet gets the request, loads any necessary data from the Model, makes any necessary updates, saves any changes via the Model, scopes any necessary data, and redirects to the View (JSP).

That's the complete MVC: Model (beans and DAO classes), View (JSPs), and Controller (Servlets).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated my original post with an example jsp page. When you say remove the logic, can I still have a couple of if statements in there to redirect to other pages? In that example I'm authenticating a user...

Comment: @viau_a Redirecting the user based on the results of authentication is very much a thing that has no business being in a view.

Comment: I suppose, so I create a java Static class for this, like I did for my DatabaseManager? Or do I put it all in a servlet? I will look it up. Thanks.

Comment: Oh cool, so I do all the navigation code in servlets, all the web forms in jsp, and then all other logic in java classes? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that there are a plethora of technologies that you can use to build web site and it is easy to get lost. For your school project, if you want learn MVC, start with a popluar web MVC framework such as [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) first.